# How do I delete all installed/built npm C++ addons?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

I upgraded my version of node.  `npm rebuild` and deleting my node_modules directory does not seem to work for me to rebuild my C++ addons.  I'm still getting this error:

```
Error: The module '[...]/node_modules/node-expat/build/Release/node_expat.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 46. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 51. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
```

I think it would be nice to just blow away all the C++ addons (or maybe just this one if you could target them) which would likely solve my problem.  Any quick and easy way to do this?

Comment: If you upgraded to 7.7, then there's a known issue with that version that will prevent all native modules from compiling. You'll need to upgrade to 7.7.1 to fix it.

Comment: This did it, thanks.  If you leave an answer I can accept it

Comment: Yeah, sure thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node recently released version 7.7, and very soon after discovered that there was a bug in it that prevented all native modules from being compiled.

Shortly they released a patch, v7.7.1, which should fix that issue. I'm guessing you upgraded to 7.7, so updating your install to 7.7.1 should solve this for ya.

Answer (score 0):

in case `npm update` won't help (that means, that for some reason it won't recompile the module, as it is supposed to do), go to the module directory and manually recompile with `make clean && make` or `npm rebuild` / `npm rb`. that's the common way of fixing such version conflicts - or at least obtaining more detailed information about the reason. removing and reinstalling the problematic module(s) might also be worth a try. without [V8](https://v8docs.nodesource.com) nodeJS can do way less, than while it's loaded (removing it might altogether only cripple down the possibilities; would not suggest to do so, despite the original question).

The documentation at [npmjs.com](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/rebuild) clearly states:

> This is useful when you install a new version of node, and **must** recompile all your C++ addons with the new binary.

... so that's the default procedure, in case of an update.